# submit form from dropdown menu text link

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jqueryform

I have dropdown menu with some actions, but I need help to submit form on click via text link and pass the name attribute to the POST method. I have jQuery already on the page and code below works but `name` attribute is not sent.

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="" method="post">

<button class="dropdown">Actions</button>
<ul class="ul_dropdown">
     <li><a href="#" name="option1" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit()">Option 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" name="option2" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit()">Option 2</a></li>
</ul>
... other form fields ...
</form>
```

Comment: you have no form input, textarea, select etc to submit. Might do some reading on how a form works. Also button within form will sumit also if isn't `type="button"`

Comment: @charlietfl of course I have it but it's not important for the question. Form need to be submited via text link and there is more then one submit link. Depending from the selected I'll process the data.

Comment: Can you update a hidden input with the name value before submit?

Comment: well your issue is not clear and should put more efort into detailing exactly what the problem is. Based on information given, and html shown there is nothing available to troubleshoot

Comment: @isherwood probably but how to update it on click and before submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul class="ul_dropdown">
     <li><a href="#" name="option1">Option 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" name="option2">Option 2</a></li>
</ul>

<input id="linkName" type="hidden" />


$('ul_dropdown li a').on('click', function() {
    $('#linkName').val( $(this).attr('name') );
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not how HTML works, a link doesnt send any information other than the url you set in the href attribute, you could do this

```
<li><a href="?name=option2" name="option2" >Option 2</a></li>
```

which does not require a form, or if you wish to Post you will need each option to be a seperate form, or you could use the solution provided by isherwood.